# How to search a text file for a specific integer

Tags: command-line, search

Is there a simple way to search a text file (source code) for all instances of a specific integer.  This should not trigger on larger numbers that happen to include the integer as a sub-string, but it can't simply exclude such lines since they could contain both cases:

searching for '6'...

```
int a=6; // found
int b=16; // not found (despite the '6' in '16')
int c=6, d=16; // found
```

I'm really looking for a command-line approach to this, but am also curious if there is a [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) GUI-type editor that will do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep -E '\b6\b'`

`\b` is a "word boundary"

Edit: After pointing @nobar in the right direction, he found/pointed out the shortcut-option `-w` (word-regexp) in the manpage, which simplifies the above to:

`grep -w 6`

If used a lot, you could use a function similar to

`wgrp(){ grep -w "$1" "$2"; }`

Note (to @glenn-jackman): If you don't quote `"$2"` here, you can use the function as a pipeline filter. But yes, then it won't work with filenames with spaces.

After reading yet another great answer from @Gilles, I now propose

`igrp(){ grep -E "(^|[^0-9])$1($|[^0-9])" "$2"; }`

Comment: Great!  After seeing your answer, I searched the `grep` man page for "word" and found that I could alternatively use this option: `-w, --word-regexp`.  So just `grep -w "6"`.

Comment: @nobar ooh, nice. Even better. Thank you :)

Comment: Also quote `"$2"`, for filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for a specific integer with a regular expression. Search for the digits preceded by either the beginning of the data or a non-digit character, and likewise after the digits.

```
grep -e '^6$' -e '^6[^0-9]' -e '[^0-9]6$' -e '[^0-9]6[^0-9]'   # BRE syntax
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])6($|[^0-9])'                                # ERE syntax
```

An entire-word search as suggested in other answers misses hits like `foo6bar`. (This may not be a problem for your use case, but it's what you asked.)

Any halfway serious text editor or viewer (e.g. `less`) has regular expression search. Check its documentation to see what regex syntax it uses.

Comment: Yep -- kind of building the whole-word option up from scratch (this roughly matches the description of the `--word-regexp` option in the `grep` man page).  A nice option if you need to customize a bit, and don't mind getting your hands dirty.  And you're right, I left some ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this wasn't such an obscure need.  My regular programming editor, [pluma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluma_(editor)) supports this via the "find" dialog using the option "Match entire word only".  I'm sure many other editors have this as well -- although at the moment, apparently not pluma's ancestor, [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit).

[image]

Comment: Hilariously, there is a gedit plugin "Find in files" that has the option to "Match entire word only", but it appears to have a bug in which it only finds the *opposite* case -- '16', but not '6'.

Comment: What OS/Version has this bug?

Comment: @AlexStragies: Ubuntu MATE 16.04.